# AngularJS - Checklist-Model doesn't update the model correctly on checkbox change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checklist-model

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm having a problem with the Checklist-Model directive.

I'm using one of their examples to replicate this behavior.
When I click one checkbox and call a function, the model seems to be updated
correctly and is shown accordingly on the template, but when I log the contents of the model on the console the value of the checkbox I clicked is missing.
Here's when the strange stuff starts. If I click the checkbox again, then the value is removed from the template but I can see it on the console.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
      <label ng-repeat="role in roles">
          <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles"
                 checklist-value="role.text"
                 ng-change="changeValues(role)"> {{role.text}}
      </label>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="checkAll()">check all</button>
  <button ng-click="uncheckAll()">uncheck all</button>
  <button ng-click="checkFirst()">check first</button>
  <br><br>
  user.roles {{ user.roles | json }}
</div>
```

Angular:

```
angular.module("DemoApp", ["checklist-model"])
.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.roles = [
    {id: 1, text: 'guest'},
    {id: 2, text: 'user'},
    {id: 3, text: 'customer'},
    {id: 4, text: 'admin'}
  ];
  $scope.user = {
    roles: ['guest', 'admin']
  };
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = $scope.roles.map(function(item) { return item.id; });
  };
  $scope.uncheckAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = [];
  };
  $scope.checkFirst = function() {
    $scope.user.roles.splice(0, $scope.user.roles.length); 
    $scope.user.roles.push(1);
  };

    $scope.changeValues = function() {
    console.log('Roles: ', JSON.stringify($scope.user.roles));
  }
});
```

The first time I click a checkbox i.e: 'User' the output on the console is:

Roles:  ["guest","admin"]

Then, when I uncheck the same checkbox the output is:

Roles:  ["guest","admin","user"]

In the application I'm developing I MUST call a function when the checkbox changes it's value that's why I using the "ng-change" directive.

Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `ng-change` directive only works on elements that have instantiated the `ngModelController`.

Comment: File an issue on GitHub with the Author of the Directive -- [GitHub vitalets/checklist-model Issues](https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model/issues). Frankly I would avoid using that directive as it is not properly integrated with the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Answer (score 0):

[checklist-model](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) it's used the Id as **checklist-value** in the checkbox and in your code you use the text.
So in the function **$scope.checkAll** you should return the **item.text** instead **item.id** and in the function **$scope.checkFirst** you should push the **$scope.roles.find(item => item.id == 1).text**
And the rest seems correct